# When Python gives you the memory location of an object, what's that for?

Tags: python

When python gives me the location of an object in memory, what is that for, other than distinguishing between instances in the interactive prompt?

Example:

```
>>>inspect.walktree
<function walktree at 0x2a97410>
```

Comment: <fun>Well it let you open your PC and look at the right RAM position what does your data looks like.</fun> I did never get what the point of that too, the only interesting stuff it provides is that you can tell if two variable are pointing the same object (for example to see if a given function copy the variable or return it modified.

Comment: @AsTeR may be it's the kind of problem I work on, but that seems like a pretty vital piece of information ;)

Comment: @delnan: You can also compare by reference using the `is` keyword.

Comment: @NiklasB.: If you have two specific objects, yes. But if you have an unknown number of objects, I'd rather try `id(obj) in set_of_ids` than loop. Of course, now I'm going beyond "at the interactive prompt".

Comment: @delnan: Yeah, that's a fine use case for `id`s, not only far "beyond the interactive prompt".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default string representation that is returned if you call `repr(obj)` on an object which doesn't define the magic `__repr__` method (or didn't override the default implementation inherited from `object`, in the case of new-style objects).

That default string has the purpose of giving the programmer useful information about the type and identity of the underlying object.

#### Additional information

Internally, the `id` function is called to get the number included in the string:

```
>>> o = object()
>>> o
<object object at 0x7fafd75d10a0>
>>> id(o)
140393209204896
>>> "%x" % id(o)
'7fafd75d10a0'
```

Note that `id` does NOT represent a unique ID. It can happen that during the lifetime of a program several objects will have the same ID (although never at the the same time).
It also **does not have to correlate with the location of the object in memory** (although it does in CPython).

You can easily override the representation string for your own classes, by the way:

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __repr__(self):
    return "meaningful representation (or is it?)"
```

Answer (score 5):

This is just a default representation for objects that don't have the [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__repr__) magic method.

Indeed, the address has no other purpose than "distinguishing between instances".

Answer (score 2):

This is an implementation detail and you shouldn't rely on it:

```
$ python
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.walktree
<function walktree at 0x7f07899c9230>
>>> id(inspect.walktree)
139670350238256

$ jython
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.walktree
<function walktree 1>
>>> id(inspect.walktree)
1
```

The number being displayed is just an identity that can be use for testing with the [`is`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#is) operator to check if two object are the same one. As already said, Whether that number is a memory location or not, is an implementation detail.

Comment: You can however rely on the fact that those IDs will be unique during the lifetime of the object.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, that's correct. My point was just to highlight that the number being displayed is an identifier that might not be a memory location.

Comment: Yeah, just thought that your sample could be misinterpreted as "the number is just be a placeholder in Jython" (because `1` looks suspiciously unmeaningful).